# Adding actions for selected text

Tags: ios

Is it possible to add actions, like Highlight or sending a Tweet, to the popup that appears when you select some text from a UIWebView?

Edit: If not, is it possible to obtain the selected text through another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject it via javascript, then send the location or href to something like "myaction://handleIt" and get it on the shouldLoad.